# How to pull physical path of a Windows Service using Get-Service command

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services, powershell-2.0

I need to pull Physical Execution paths of all the Windows Services on a Set of Servers, that run  on Win 2k8. As, the powershell version that is shipped with this OS is 2.0, I wanted to use Get-service command instead of Get-WmiObject.
I know that I can pull the physical path using the command given below

```
$QueryApp = "Select * from Win32_Service Where Name='AxInstSV'"
$Path = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName MyServer -Query $QueryApp).PathName
```

I donot want this command to pull the physical path but wanted to use Get-Service command that comes with PS Version 2.0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Even with PowerShell 3, I don't see a way to get it with Get-Service.

This 1-liner will get you the pathname, albeit with a little less of the preferred "filter left" behavior:

```
gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -eq "AxInstSV"}|select pathname
```

Or, if you want just the string itself:

```
(gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -eq "AxInstSV"}).pathname
```

Comment: That .NET code is doing exactly what this PowerShell code is doing, just more verbosely.

Answer (score 4):

@alroc did good, but there's no reason to filter all services. Querying WMI is like querying a DB, and you can just ask WMI to do the filtering for you:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter 'Name = "AxInstSV"').PathName
```

To explore all of the meta available for that service:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter 'Name = "AxInstSV"' | Select-Object *
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do something similar, but based on searching / matching the path of the process running under the service, so I used the classic WMI Query syntax, then passed the results through format-table:

```
$pathWildSearch = "orton";
gwmi -Query "select * from win32_service where pathname like '%$pathWildSearch%' and state='Running'" | Format-Table -Property Name, State, PathName -AutoSize -Wrap
```

You're welcome to turn this into a one-liner by skipping defining and passing $pathWildSearch, or you could just back gwmi statement up to continue after the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps little less verbose,

```
wmic service where "name='AxInstSV'" get PathName
```

This should work on command prompt as well, not just powershell.

---

Or else if you have process name itself you could do:

```
wmic process where "name='AxInstSV.exe'" get ExecutablePath
```

To read process path you would need permission, so mostly I have better luck with service name.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to do this through the Get-Service command but if your service runs as it's own process then you can use the Get-Process command for this via the following code:

```
(Get-Process -Name AxInstSV).path
```

Source:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/15/powertip-use-powershell-to-find-path-for-processes/